Can the derivation of the BIC be simply extended to multivariate observations?
Under the assumption that observations are univariate and i.i.d., the classical definition of the Bayesian Information Criterion for a model $\mathcal{M}$ and a dataset $\mathcal{D}$ is
$$
BIC = -2 \log (\hat{L}) + \log(T)k 
$$
where $T$ is the number of independent observations in $\mathcal{D}$, $k$ is the number of free parameters in $\mathcal{M}$, and $\hat{L}$ is the maximized likelihood of $\mathcal{M}$ for $\mathcal{D}$.
If we further assume that observation errors follow a normal distribution, i.e. if the observations $\{y_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq T}$ are defined as $y_i = m x_i + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$, then the BIC can be simplified as
$$
BIC = T \log (\hat{\sigma}) + \log(T)k
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}$ is the estimated value of $\sigma$.
The above equalities were derived in the univariate case (i.e. for scalar values of $y_i$). Let's now consider the multivariate case, e.g. where observations are $d$-dimensional vectors. The multivariate linear regression problem becomes
$$
Y = XB + U
$$
where $Y$ is a $T \times d$ matrix containing the observations, $X$ is a $T \times k$ input matrix, $B$ is a $k \times d$ matrix of parameters to be estimated, and the rows of $U$ have a null mean and a covariance matrix $\Sigma$. In this case, the BIC is defined as
$$
BIC = T \log (|\hat{\Sigma}|) + \log(T)(kd + \frac{d(d+1)}{2})
$$
which is similar to the univariate case except for $|\hat{\Sigma}|$ substituted to $\hat{\sigma}$ and with $kd + \frac{d(d+1)}{2}$ free parameters ($kd$ free parameters to estimate $B$, and $\frac{d(d+1)}{2}$ free parameters to estimate $\Sigma$, see [1][2][3]).
My question is the following: in the general case (i.e. not focusing solely on linear regression), can the classical definition of the BIC (first equation above) be extended to multivariate settings?
In this case, the number of observations $T$ would be the number of independent observations $y_i$, each of them being $d$-dimensional. I cannot think of a step in the classical derivation of the BIC that can not be extended to the multivariate case.
The following paper [4] addresses the problem differently. The authors assume that, in this setting, the number of observations should not be $T$, but rather $Td$ (i.e. the sum of all univariate values in each independent vectors). Since these $Td$ values are not i.i.d., they have to come up with correction terms for the BIC. I am wondering whether this can be avoided.
